# How to extract the href link inside a particular td in python with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I have the snippet that extract two tds. Every td has a link. I wanted to extract the link inside the (token) td. Any help or ideas will be very helpful.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re, random, ctypes
import requests
from time import sleep


url = 'https://bscscan.com/tokentxns'

user_agent_list = [
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0Gecko/20100101         Firefox/86.0'}",
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'}",
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15'}",
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'}",
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36'}",
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.67 Safari/537.36'}"
]

header = random.choice(user_agent_list)
req = requests.get(url,header, timeout=10)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr')

for row in rows[1:]: 
    txnhash = row.find_all('td')[1].text[0:]
    token = row.find_all('td')[8].text[0:] #-- I wanted to extract the link inside this td
    print (str(txnhash) + str(token))
```

Sample Output:

```
 0x58a4254f8dafffd846a15d32939e98b290e76c5b32dbf9ab453911c31340f84e Wrapped BNB (WBNB) TD-LINK 
 0x58a4254f8dafffd846a15d32939e98b290e76c5b32dbf9ab453911c31340f84e PathFund (PATH) TD-LINK 
 0x43aa8ad160bd7f6aa7a740dfd561abfece3b118a5fd2488f4c35b2edf1bec3ff SyrupBar Tok... (SYRUP) TD-LINK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the link it would be needed to get `href` attribute of the `a` element inside of the given `td` element:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

for row in rows[1:]:
    tds = row.find_all('td')
    txnhash = tds[1].text[0:]
    token = tds[8].text[0:]
    # retrieve the link
    link = urljoin(url, tds[8].find('a')['href'])
    print (str(txnhash) + str(token) + ' ' + link)
```

The `href` attribute contains URL relative to the base URL, therefore function `urljoin()` can be used to get absolute URL.

Answer (score 1):

Since each link starts with `/token/` you can use a filter function to search for the first tag with appropriate `'href'` attribute value:

```py
for row in rows[1:]
    token = row.find(href = lambda h: h is not None and h.startswith("/token/"))["href"]
    print(token)
```